# Why can't selenium find this seemingly simple element from my xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm fairly new to Selenium, but this bug is just knocking my knickers!
I'm trying to code a bot to click the like button on the first 10 photos in my Instagram feed.  I just copied and pasted the XPath of the like button from Chrome, but this XPath won't work for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint


sleep(3)    
for x in range(1,10):
    button_like = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[{}]/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span'.format(x))
    button_like.click()
    sleep(randint(2,3))
```

And here's the HTML of the section with the buttons I'm trying to click.

```
<section class="ltpMr Slqrh">
    <span class="FY9nT fr66n">
        <button class="dCJp8 afkep _0mzm-">
            <span class="glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5 u-__7" aria-label="Unlike"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="_15y0l">
        <button class="dCJp8 afkep _0mzm-">
            <span class="glyphsSpriteComment__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="Comment"></span>
        </button></span>
    <span class="_5e4p">
        <button class="dCJp8 afkep _0mzm-">
            <span class="glyphsSpriteShare__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="Share Post"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="wmtNn">
        <button class="dCJp8 afkep _0mzm-">
            <span class="glyphsSpriteSave__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="Save"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</section>
```

And here's the error message I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/JoshSong/Desktop/Liking Your Friend's Photos.py", line 33, in 
>       button_like = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[{}]/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span'.format(x))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span"}
>     (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Comment: try this //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span

Comment: ah that got the same error unfortunately

Comment: you need to share the xml/html

Comment: I shared the html of the button above.  Do you want me to share more of the html?

Comment: yes, from section/main

Comment: Thanks metal.  I copied the html from the entire section and updated the post.  (The entire section copied as a single line which is kind of nasty to read, I'm trying to figure out how to make that nicer to read for you)

Comment: I don't see issue with `//section[1]/span[1]/button/span` part. Have to checked if the xpath is working in the browser dev tools? And make sure to check if there are no iframes.

Comment: Try `//span[@aria-label="Save"]`

Comment: Unfortunately, //span[@aria-label="Save"] gave the same error.  Even if it did work, I am trying to click on the class="glyphsSpriteHeart", and not on the class "glyphsSpriteSave". Thanks so much tho!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have similar issues when trying to use paths with indices. I would suggest using this: //span[@aria-label='Like'] . I haven't used selenium with python but I'd assume that there is a find method that takes an index as parameter. So you could use that to hit the first like element, then the 2nd, and so on (but from what it seems like on instagram website only 7 are detectable at a time)

Comment: This is the only solution that was worked so far! However, it clicks everything with the aria-label = 'Like', including the comments. I don't want to click on the comments, only the main post. The comments have a different class than the main post. Is there any way I can distinguish xpaths by class, so I can click on the main post but not the comments?

Comment: It's solved!  Thank you so much PreciseMotion!  The line I used was buttons = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9') and contains(@aria-label, 'Like')]")

Comment: Glad you figured it out! @JoshuaSong, sorry I wasn't able to answer your first comment quick enough.

Comment: Naw you set me on the right track, I couldn't have done it without you.  Hope you have a fantastic week!

Answer (score 0):

We need more of the HTML to be able to answer the question adequately. For example, with what you provided, one solution would be:

```
like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='FY9nT fr66n']/button")
like_button.click()
```

Based on the provided HTML, this would click the first button (which is actually an Unlike button from what you provided, but I'm assuming the Like button WAS there). If the span elements surrounding each of the Like buttons you want has the same class, this would only require minor modification:

```
like_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='FY9nT fr66n']/button")
#create maxIndex of the lesser of the length, or the max index you want to press
maxIndex = MIN(9, len(like_buttons))
for i in range (0, maxIndex):
    like_buttons[i].click()
```

This solution should work, assuming the span elements surrounding each Like button are the same AND that that class is not reused on other span elements on the page that are not wrapping Like buttons. If you update the HTML and these assumptions are violated, I would be happy to review a new solution